# IPC using .NET Core that supports duplex channel or callbacks

Tags: wcf, callback, .net-core, ipc

I am evaluating .NET Core 2.0 for IPC communication. I found that .NET Core does not support WCF on the server side. What can be used in .NET Core for inter-process communication along with callbacks (for publish-subscribe) model?

Answer (score 6):

If you're ready to go low-level, you can use [named pipes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.pipes), but you'll have to implement publish/subscribe pattern yourself.

At a higher level, you can look into libraries like [ZeroMQ](https://zeromq.org/)/[NetMQ](https://github.com/zeromq/netmq) - these are very thin layer on top of sockets with support of various patterns (like publish/subscribe).

Even higher level are true message queues - [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/).

And of course, the native way is Web API using ASP.NET Core.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Igor. is there anyway we can enable duplex or pubsub communication in web api using asp.net core?

Comment: Web API does not support duplex or pubsub. But WebSockets do (at least surely duplex). The `System.Net.WebSockets` namespace seems to be supported in .NET Core.

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar need but the existing solutions out there had too many dependencies for my liking and did not support proper two-way communication.

So I wrote the [PipeMethodCalls](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PipeMethodCalls) package:

```cs
var pipeServer = new PipeServerWithCallback<IConcatenator, IAdder>(
    new NetJsonPipeSerializer(),
    "mypipe",
    () => new Adder());
await pipeServer.WaitForConnectionAsync();
string concatResult = await pipeServer.InvokeAsync(c => c.Concatenate("a", "b"));
```

```cs
var pipeClient = new PipeClientWithCallback<IAdder, IConcatenator>(
    new NetJsonPipeSerializer(),
    "mypipe",
    () => new Concatenator());
await pipeClient.ConnectAsync();
int result = await pipeClient.InvokeAsync(a => a.AddNumbers(4, 7));
```

It serializes the method name and arguments as JSON or MessagePack, invokes it on the other side, then packages the response to send back.

Comment: Looks great, but couldn't reference to my `.NET 4.5`, since this is only `.NET Core`

Comment: @AlexG the library is .NET Standard 2.0 so you would need at least `.NET 4.6.1` to use it. The API it uses does not exist in earlier versions of .NET Standard.

Comment: This was _almost_ the answer for me, but I needed to run the server as a Windows service and ran into UnauthorizedAccessExceptions. .Net Standard apparently does not have an implementation of PipeSecurity, so it seems as though I'm out of luck with this. It worked fantastically up to the point that I discovered that, though.